# _Global_ list in Java

Tags: java, list, data-structures, global, extern

I am developing a java program for class, and I have some **restrictions** that are killing me. I have to read a file and save its words on a list, and then keep that list so I can take words out of it.

I have to read the file and select *n* words out of the list, and return those words, not the whole list. My question is: is there some way of creating the complete list as global or extern, so every method can access to it, with no need to be a parameter?? I need to be modifying the complete list, removing the words I am needing, and then using it again in other methods.

Thank you :)

Comment: Make the list a public static member of one of your classes. That way it can be accesses from anywhere. That's an ok solution for a quick+dirty practice application.

Comment: [static](https://www.javatpoint.com/static-keyword-in-java) is your friend..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a member variable in a class `public` and `static`, and that way you can access it from anywhere:

```
public class One {
    public static List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class Two {
    public void addName(String name) {
        One.names.add(name);
    }
}

public class Three {
    public void printTheNames() {
        System.out.println(One.names);
    }
}
```

However...

These restrictions (like no way to create true global variables) are there for a good reason, and not because Java is lacking features. If you have trouble with these restrictions, then that's a sign you are trying to do things the wrong way - it means the design of your program has problems.

Almost always, [global variables are bad](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad).

Answer (score 0):

You can get a globally accessible variable by making it a **public static**. In terms of design principles, though, this is generally a bad idea because it tends to lead to rampant dependencies that are hard to replace later one.